# Showing that the least-square method minimizes error

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Assume that the relation between temperature and time is defined as follows:
$$T = A^kC$$
We can find parameters $A$ and $C$ using the least-square method. The given relation is not linear, but we can circumvent this problem using the following relation between $log(T)$ and $k$:
$$log(T) = k log(A) + log(C)$$
How can I show that because of this transformation, the least-square method, bij approach, minimizes the sum of the squares of relative temperature errors (given that these are small enough)?